# Clothing value for customs in Canada

Tags: canada

When moving to Canada what I should claim as the value of clothing I have worn and bring into the country?

Comment: If the question is in regard to duty payable on imported clothing and fabrics, I would say "nominal".

Comment: Please check out [this page](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/mrc-drc-eng.html). Clothing is part of your household goods and won't have any duty assessed.

Comment: if you're just visiting and the clothes aren't staying, you don't declare them. If you're moving to Canada, ask on Expatriates.

Comment: Yeah, immigration questions belong on expats.  Click "flag" click "moderator intervention" and write "move to expats.se" in the text box.  They'll take care of it.

Comment: Unfortunately the person that asked this question probably doesn't know it is now on a different site.  Even worse, because mail is associated with membership in individual sites and not in the global SE mechanism, the user certainly won't be informed of any comments or answers that the question receives.  I suspect this is a too common occurrence for new SE users.

Answer (score 3):

If you are immigrating, you can bring whatever personal posessions are reasonable:

- If it's something you already own *and use*, then it's personal property and exempt from customs duty.
- If it's new, or something you bought because of the relocation, it could be subject to duty.

The clothing you normally wear would obviously count as personal possessions, while new going-away gifts from relatives might be subject to duty.

The key word is "reasonable".

Settlement.org says:

[I am immigrating to Canada. How do I bring my belongings with me?](https://settlement.org/ontario/immigration-citizenship/landing-and-leaving/landing-in-canada/i-am-immigrating-to-canada-how-do-i-bring-my-belongings-with-me/)

> If you are moving permanently to Canada, you can bring your belongings
>   with you when you arrive or you may send them later.
>
> You may be able to bring your belongings with you duty-free. To
>   qualify, usually you must have owned, possessed, and used the goods
>   before coming to Canada.
>
> You also have to fill out a BSF186 - Personal Effects Accounting
>   Document, where you list any goods with you and the goods that you
>   will send later. If your goods are not listed on your original BSF186,
>   they are not eligible for duty-free importation at a later time.
>
> If you need more space to list your goods, you can type out your own
>   list or fill out form BSF186A - Personal Effects Accounting Document.
>
> Your list should state the goods and their value. Make a list of the
>   goods that are with you and another list for those that will arrive
>   later. It is good to have a copy each list.
>
> You have to give these lists to the customs officer when you arrive in
>   Canada, even if you are not bringing in anything at that time.

Settlement.org is funded by both the Canadian federal government and the Ontario provincial government.

It contains Ontario-specific information (schools, health plans, driver's licences, provincial government services, etc.), as well as information for specific areas within the province.

But anything it says related to immigration, customs duty, etc. would be true for all of Canada.
(In Canada, movement between provinces is effectively unregulated, with a few exceptions, such as transporting large quantities of alcohol.)

The official federal government documentation is at [Moving or returning to Canada](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/mrc-drc-eng.html).

Comment: Is settlement.org an official site?  Is its information reliable?  From a quick glance at the page, it seems to be at least semi-official and therefore probably reliable, but I am not sure.  A gc.ca site would be a better source, or at least a link to the relevant law (or even an unlinked citation).

Comment: @phoog, yes, settlement.org is a reliable government-funded site.  See my update at end of posting.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, and for the update.  I already upvoted, so I can't do it again.